# Htaccess - document root

Tags: htaccess

Gostaria de fazer o seguinte:

```
#diretorio não existe
www.teste.com.br/diretorio
```

toda a vez que acessar esse endereço, o apache abriria:

```
#outro_diretorio/pagina esse existira
www.teste.com.br/outro_diretorio/pagina
```

porém toda a navegação seria exibida ao usuário a partir `www.teste.com.br/diretorio` dando a impressão que o conteúdo esteja dentro da pasta "`diretorio`". Não sei se me fiz entender.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui, era isso que estava precisando:

```
RewriteRule ^meu_diretorio_que_nao_existe\/(.*)$ diretorio/outro_diretorio/$1 [QSA,L]
```